# Okteto service restarts and fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm working on a project using Okteto to deploy my services. I'm not sure why but one of my services keeps restarting and then fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXw4H.png)

It has worked before but since I added an api-gateway it stopped.

My main-flow.yaml

```
name: Build and deliver containers

on: push

jobs:
  customerservice:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Java 17 build, test, deliver customer-service container
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          cache: maven
          distribution: adopt

      - name: Build, test and package project
        working-directory: customer-service
        run: mvn package -DskipTests

      - name: Docker login
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Build
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/customer-service:latest ./customer-service

      - name: Upload container to Docker Hub with Push
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/customer-service:latest
  taxiservice:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Java 17 build, test, deliver taxi-service container
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          cache: maven
          distribution: adopt

      - name: Build, test and package project
        working-directory: taxi-service
        run: mvn package -DskipTests

      - name: Docker login
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Build
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/taxi-service:latest ./taxi-service

      - name: Upload container to Docker Hub with Push
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/taxi-service:latest
  tripservice:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Java 17 build, test, deliver trip-service container
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          cache: maven
          distribution: adopt

      - name: Build, test and package project
        working-directory: trip-service
        run: mvn package -DskipTests

      - name: Docker login
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Build
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/trip-service:latest ./trip-service

      - name: Upload container to Docker Hub with Push
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/trip-service:latest
  apigateway:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Java 17 build, test, deliver ede-api-gateway container
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          cache: maven
          distribution: adopt

      - name: Build, test and package project
        working-directory: ./api-gateway
        run: mvn package -DskipTests

      - name: Docker login
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Build
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/ede-project-api-gateway:latest ./api-gateway

      - name: Upload container to Docker Hub with Push
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/ede-project-api-gateway:latest
```

And my docker-compose

```
services:
  mongo-customers:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_customer_data:/data/db

  mysql-trip:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql_trip_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: trippassword

  mysql-taxi:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql_taxi_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: taxipassword

  customer-service:
    depends_on:
      - mongo-customers
    image: compacte/customer-service
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    links:
      - mongo-customers
    environment:
      MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      MONGODB_HOST: mongo-customers

  taxi-service:
    depends_on:
      - mysql-taxi
    image: compacte/taxi-service
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    links:
      - mysql-taxi
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: taxipassword
      MYSQL_DB_HOST: mysql-taxi
      MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3307

  trip-service:
    depends_on:
      - taxi-service
      - customer-service
    image: compacte/trip-service
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    links:
      - taxi-service
      - customer-service
    environment:
      CUSTOMER_SERVICE_BASEURL: customer-service:8081
      TAXI_INFO_SERVICE_BASEURL: taxi-service:8082
      MYSQL_DB_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: trippassword
      MYSQL_DB_HOST: mysql-trip
      MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3306
    
  api-gateway:
    depends_on:
      - taxi-service
      - trip-service
    image: compacte/ede-project-api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    links:
      - taxi-service
      - trip-service
    environment:
      TAXI_SERVICE_BASEURL: taxi-service:8082
      TRIP_SERVICE_BASEURL: trip-service:8083

volumes:
  mongodb_customer_data:
  mysql_taxi_data:
  mysql_trip_data:
```

If anything is unclear, please ask away

I've checked all indents since yaml is quiet sensitive but they should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be because you have hardcoded `datasource` to `localhost`: https://github.com/SeppeVE/EDE/blob/main/taxi-service/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1

You need to get it from the environment variables you have definied in your docker compose:

```
 MYSQL_DB_HOST: mysql-taxi
 MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3307
```

Similar to what you have done for the `trip-service` here: https://github.com/SeppeVE/EDE/blob/main/trip-service/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1

Let me know if it still doesn't work. Also would recommend reaching out on the Okteto community forum for faster support :) https://community.okteto.com/

Comment: Oh I totally missed that, thanks! Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ah! Could you post in the community forum then. That's the best way to get help!